# How do I replace all newline sections of any length with a single newline?

Tags: regular-expression

I would like to replace every section of newlines - for example, a single newline at the end of a line, or 5 newlines at the end of a line until the next line of text - with a single newline.

I tried to do this with:

`:%s/$\n*/\r/`, but this did not result in a bunch of lines with the exact same amount of newlines between them.

Maybe the problem is that some of the seemingly "blank" lines actually have a space on them, so the expression is treating 3 blank lines as 3 separate matches and re-inserting 3 carriage returns in total.

In general, what is the most standard regex for "any amount of blank space from the end of a line with text in it until the next line with text in it", or what would be a good way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost did it with `:%s/$\n*/\r/`.

Try simpler one:

```
:%s/\n\+/\r
```

But if you want to remove all empty lines try even simpler:

```
:%s/^\s*$//
```

**Update**

if your text looks like:

```
there are


   

   

empty lines with 


some spaces

  

   that

has to be deleted
```

Where there are lines with spaces and you want to get

```
there are
empty lines with 
some spaces
    that
has to be deleted
```

Then `%s/\n\_s*$//g` would do it.

See `:h /\_s` for details.

PS, if you also need to delete trailing whitespaces then it would be even simpler: `%s/\_s*$//g`

PPS if you want to replace it with some constant number of newlines:

```
%s/\n\_s*$/\r\r/g
```

will replace all empty lines with 2:

```
there are    


empty lines with 


some spaces


   that


has to be deleted
```

PPPS, how to add N number of `\r` I have answered on your other question.

Comment: I think your last expression should be ˋ%s/^\s*\n//ˋ.

Comment: The first one will replace any number of newlines with a single newline, but it will still treat a newline, then a space, then a newline as two separate matches instead of one. The second one removes blank newlines, but it only works for collapsing sequences of blank lines to nothing, whereas I actually want to replace regions of blank lines with some number of blank lines, i.e. consistently 4 newlines, for example. So I think I need something that says, "the end of a line followed by any number of newlines or whitespace in any order". I think this might be $[\n, \s]* ?

Comment: It would be way simpler you had provided an example text in your question, @JohnSmith

Comment: @JohnSmith I have updated the answer with some text before -> text after and the command